# Insert multiple items into List or Array (no Linq and not quite CodeGolf)

Tags: c#, vb.net, arrays, algorithm

No matter how I try, I can't seem to create a nice and clean algorithm for doing the following:

1. System.Array (or generic List) *data* of System.Object
2. System.Array (or generic List) *xval* of System.Object
3. System.Array (or generic List) *idxs* of System.Int32

*xval* and *idxs* contain the same number of elements and *idxs* contains no values less than zero or larger than *data.Length*

I need to insert all elements in *xval* into the *data* array, where the associated integer in *idxs* represents the insertion index in the original, unmolested *data*.

For example:

```
*data* = {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H}
*xval* = {U, V, W, X, Y, Z}
*idxs* = {5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}

*output* = {V, W, X, A, Y, Z, B, C, D, E, U, F, G, H}
```

It's easy enough to do, but I always end up with icky code. My best attempt so far (but I'm worried about rounding errors):

```
  idxs.Reverse()
  xval.Reverse()

  Dim N As Int32 = data.Count + xval.Count
  Dim map(N - 1) As Double
  Dim output(N - 1) As Object

  Dim k As Int32 = -1
  For i As Int32 = 0 To data.Count - 1
    k += 1
    map(k) = i
    output(k) = data(i)
  Next
  For i As Int32 = 0 To xval.Count - 1
    k += 1
    map(k) = idxs(i) - ((i + 1) * 1e-8)
    output(k) = xval(i)
  Next

  Array.Sort(map, output)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my attempt, which doesn’t use `IndexOf`, `Sort`, `Reverse`, dictionaries, or doubles.

```
// input data
char[] data = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H' };
char[] xval = { 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
int[] idxs = { 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 };

// algorithm starts here
var output = new List<char>(data);
for (int i = 0; i < idxs.Length; i++)
{
    // Insert the i’th item in the right place
    output.Insert(idxs[i], xval[i]);

    // Increment all the following indexes so that they
    // will insert in the right place
    for (int j = i + 1; j < idxs.Length; j++)
        if (idxs[j] >= idxs[i])
            idxs[j]++;
}

// outputs V, W, X, A, Y, Z, B, C, D, E, U, F, G, H
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", output));
```

Of course, if you don’t want the algorithm to modify the `idxs` array, then simply make a copy of it first.

Comment: It can't get much clearer than this, in my opinion.  (Although rather than incrementing the numbers in the `idxs` array, I would keep a integer counter of how many inserts I've done and add that to each index as I went on.)

Comment: @mquander: I would love to see your code for that, because I don’t see how you can do that. Want to paste it at pastebin.com and post the link here in a comment?

Comment: Yep, this is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.  I mis-thought it through; your solution is definitely the clearest.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for something like this (replace 'char' with 'object')

```
char[] data = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H' };
char[] xval = new char[] { 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
int[] idxs = new int[] { 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 };
List<char> output = data.ToList();

Dictionary<int, List<char>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<char>>();
for (int i = 0; i < idxs.Length; i++)
{
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(idxs[i]))
        dict.Add(idxs[i], new List<char>());
    dict[idxs[i]].Add(xval[i]);
}
List<int> keys = dict.Keys.ToList();
keys.Sort();
keys.Reverse();
foreach (int key in keys)
    output.InsertRange(key,dict[key]);
```

Comment: Clever. Not marking as the answer yet in a vain hope someone comes up with a smaller solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
'*data* = {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H}
'*xval* = {U, V, W, X, Y, Z}
'*idxs* = {5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}
'*output* = {V, W, X, A, Y, Z, B, C, D, E, U, F, G, H}
    Dim data As New List(Of String)
    Dim xval As New List(Of String)
    Dim idxs As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim output As New List(Of String)

    data.AddRange(New String() {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"})
    xval.AddRange(New String() {"U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"})
    idxs.AddRange(New Integer() {5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1})

    For x As Integer = 0 To data.Count - 1 'for each item in the data
        Dim idx As Integer = idxs.IndexOf(x)
        Do While idx <> -1 'do we have xval's for this index
            output.Add(xval(idx)) 'yes add it
            xval.RemoveAt(idx) 'remove the items from xval
            idxs.RemoveAt(idx) 'and idxs
            idx = idxs.IndexOf(x)
        Loop
        output.Add(data(x)) 'add data item to list
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks.  I try to keep things like this as simple as possible.

Comment: An educated guess would be that Timwi's solution would be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there's no inversion of the lists.

```
    IList<Object> data = new Object[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H" };
    IList<Object> xval = new Object[] { "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };
    IList<int> idxs = new int[] { 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 };

    List<Object> output = new List<object>(data);

    for (int i = 0; i < xval.Count; i++)
    {
        int currentIndex = idxs[i];
        Object dataElement= data[currentIndex]; // We should insert the new element before this element.
        int elementsIndex = output.IndexOf(dataElement);
        output.Insert(elementsIndex, xval[i]);
    }
    return output;
```

Comment: Jeroen, good attempt, but IndexOf cannot be trusted. The list might contain the same object multiple times or it might contain multiple nulls.

Comment: In that case the answer of Timwi is the one to go for at the moment.